# Reflection Formulas for the $\Gamma$ Function

Tags: reference-request, riemann-zeta-function, functional-equations, gamma-function

We have

> $$\begin{align}
> &\Gamma\Big(1~+~x\Big)~\cdot~\Gamma\Big(1-x\Big)~=~\frac{\pi x}{\sin\pi x}
> \\\\
> &\Gamma\Big(\tfrac12+x\Big)~\cdot~\Gamma\Big(\tfrac12-x\Big)~=~\frac\pi{\cos\pi x}
> \\\\
> &\Gamma\Big(\tfrac14+x\Big){\bigg/}\Gamma\Big(\tfrac14-x\Big)~=~\pi^{2x}\cdot\frac{\zeta\Big(\tfrac12-2x\Big)}{\zeta\Big(\tfrac12+2x\Big)}
> \end{align}$$

where the latter is nothing else than the [functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_Xi_function) of the [Riemann $\zeta$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function). I was

wondering whether yet another similar relation might also exist, involving either $\Gamma\Big(\tfrac18\pm x\Big)$

or $\Gamma\Big(\tfrac13\pm x\Big).$

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342820/more-general-reflection-formula-for-gamma-function